# What exactly is a inverse $\chi^2$ distribution?

Tags: distributions, definition, inverse-gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

What exactly is a inverse-chi square distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ has a chisquare distribution, then $\frac1X$ has the inverse chisquare distribution. For details see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-chi-squared_distribution).  Note that it is a special case of the [inverse gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution).